# Как в контроллере вызвать методы окна в Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx

Всем здравствуйте.
Мне нужно, чтобы после закрытия окна происходили некоторые действия. Я нашёл вот такое заклинание по отслеживанию закрытия окна, вот только я не пойму, как мне в контроллере обратиться ко всему окну, а не к отдельным элементам (типа именно к Stage). Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
         System.out.println("Stage is closing");
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Окно можно получить из любого элемента на окне.

```
Window window =       anyNode.getScene().getWindow();
Stage stage = (Stage) anyNode.getScene().getWindow();
```

Comment: Можно получить ноду через аргумент метода `we.getTarget()`, но я не знаю что именно WindowEvent отдаст